# How do I send a set of file paths to cat and display their contents?

Tags: linux, files, find, cat

to be more specific ,I want to display **contents of files from output of `find`** **command**,I tried the following commands but they don't get my work done

- `cat < find . -name "*.txt"`
- `find . -name "*.txt" | cat`

Answer (score 4):

Either

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs cat --
```

or (better, if you have GNU `find`)

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 cat --
```

or

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cat -- {} +
```

Comment: +1; or `cat $(find ...)`

Comment: It might make sense to use `cat --` to prevent unwanted file option matches.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens thanks, good point - will edit

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens - how could that happen when all file names returned by `find` start with `.` ?

Comment: @Videonauth (and whoever upvoted your comment) - that will fail if  filenames contain any IFS chars - [see the answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/22142) - newlines in file names exist only in theory but spaces are pretty common in real life...

Comment: @don_crissti fair point. But since the answer uses also `xargs` your second comment  to @Videonauth applies.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below the below command to display contents of files

Method 1:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec cat {} \;
```

Method 2:

```
ls -ltr *.txt | awk '{print "cat" " " $9}' | sh
```

Comment: The second method has some issues. First `ls` behaves very differently on different OSs. Second building shell scripts on the run is a little bit of over doing it.